# Error when ran a python (3.8.2) file in windows 10 command promt

Tags: python, cmd, syntax-error

I just started learning Python programming. I wrote a simple program in python 3.8.2:

```
x = "Hi world"
print (x)
```

The code was saved in a Python file named 'file.py'. It ran correctly in python. The problem is when I try to run the same chunk of code in the command line of windows 10.

After cmd (in Windows) was opened, I set the path at the directory where the file is saved, in this case, my desktop. Then i tried to run the next command:

```
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop>python file.py
```

The program did not work. Windows shows me the following error message:

```
File "file.py", line 1 Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I fix this error? I will appreciate all your help.

Comment: "_It ran correctly in python_" - What is this supposed to mean? What program did you use to run it?

Comment: Means that i run the chunk in in python console, PyCharm and python (opened directly in the cmd), and in all cases the output was the expected "Hi world", but when tried to open the file.py, it fails

Comment: Are you sure you're running it with the correct Python installation?

Comment: What do you mean? I installed python 3.8.2 from its webpage on todays morning and the same file works when python console or IDE was use

Comment: The code that you provided is valid in _any_ version of python. Check if file.py is indeed the same file.